# Relationship between differential and partial derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a complex manifold and let $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$. Let $\{\partial_i\}$ denote the standard local frame on the tangent bundle. Let $(\phi,U)$ be a chart on $M$ with $p \in U$. Is the following true in general?
\begin{equation}
\partial_{z_i}(f \circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))=(d_p f)(\partial_i(p))
\end{equation}

If this is not the case, is there some other relationship between partial derivatives and the differential?

Comment: RHS that you wrote is just a tangent vector, i.e. it is missing a function it acts on. It should be $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ again, right?

Comment: Sorry, fixed RHS

Comment: I take it that you want to identify $T_p\mathbb C \cong\mathbb C$? Also, is $\phi = (z_1,\ldots, z_n)$? In other words, is $\left.\partial_{z_i}\right|_{\phi(p)} = (d\phi_p)(\left.\partial_i\right|_p)$?

Comment: Yep, what you wrote for $\phi$ is the chart I would like to consider. And I'm identifying $T_p(\mathbb{C})$ with $\mathbb{C}$ as you mentioned.

Comment: In that case, the LHS is equal to $(\partial_i|_p)(f)$. The RHS is also equal to the same thing by the definition of covector field $df: M\to T^*M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me denote by $\varphi_*\colon T_pM\to T_{\varphi(p)}N$ the pushforward of $\varphi\colon M\to N$ and for a function $f\colon M\to \mathbb C$, let $df\colon M\to T^*M$ be its differential.

If $(U,\phi)$, $\phi = (z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ is a chart, we have that $\partial_{z_i}|_{\phi(p)} = \phi_*(\partial_i(p))$. Then,

\begin{align}\partial_{z_i}(f\circ\phi^{-1})(\phi(p)) &= \phi_*(\partial_i(p))(f\circ \phi^{-1})\\
&= (\partial_i(p))(f\circ\phi^{-1}\circ\phi)\\
&= (\partial_i(p))(f)\\
&= (df_p)(\partial_i(p))
\end{align}

where the last equality is true since by definition $(df_p)(X) = X(f)$, for any $X\in T_pM$.

---

Perhaps instead of considering covector field (differential $1$-form) $df$, you wanted to see the connection with pushforward $f_*\colon T_pM\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb C.$ For that we need to elaborate on the isomorphism $T_q\mathbb C\cong\mathbb C$.

In general, for vector space $V$, we have isomorphism $V\to T_qV$ that sends vector $v$ to directional derivative defined by $v$: $g\mapsto \frac d{dt}g(p + tv)|_{t=0}.$ In the case when $V = \mathbb C$, we can easily write it's inverse as $X\mapsto X(\operatorname{id_{\mathbb C}})\colon T_q\mathbb C\to\mathbb C.$ All in all, for any $X\in T_pM$ we have

$$f_*(X)(\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb C}) = X(\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb C}\circ f) = Xf = (df_p)(X).$$

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!